# How can make logarithm distribution bin in R?

Tags: r

i'm beginner for R and math.

We are operating a device to measure fine dust by particle size. The instrument analyzes 0.3-10 um with 16 channels. Each channel is divided according to the log normal distribution as shown in the table below.

```
          Lower         Upper
1           0.3          0.374
2           0.374        0.465
3           0.465        0.579
4           0.579        0.721
5           0.721        0.897
6           0.897        1.117
7           1.117        1.391
8           1.391        1.732
9           1.732        2.156
10          2.156        2.685
11          2.685        3.343
12          3.343        4.162
13          4.162        5.182
14          5.182        6.451
15          6.451        8.032
16          8.032        10
```

I want to adjust the table again to 0.3-2.5 um. How can I set up an interval evenly? I tried to write code using R, but it's very difficult.

```
          Lower         Upper
1           0.3          
2                   
3                   
4                   
5                   
6                   
7                   
8                   
9                   
10                  
11                  
12                  
13                  
14                  
15                  
16                       2.5
```

The graph shape is assumed to be log-normal.

Comment: please do not post images of data. Use `dput` to include the data structure in your question. Also include the code you have tried and where you are getting stuck

Comment: Thank you for reply, i changed table format.

Comment: The `rescale` function from the __scales__ package _may_ help, but the problem is that you don't know what the second value of the`to` argument should be for the Lower (the first value is 0.3) and you don't know what the _first_ value should be for the Upper (the second value is 2.5) !

Answer (score 1):

You can use `seq`, `log` and `exp` to create the *log spaced Table*:

```
tt <- exp(seq(log(0.3), log(2.5), length.out=17))
data.frame(Lower=tt[-length(tt)], Upper=tt[-1])
#       Lower     Upper
#1  0.3000000 0.3425093
#2  0.3425093 0.3910422
#3  0.3910422 0.4464520
#4  0.4464520 0.5097133
#5  0.5097133 0.5819385
#6  0.5819385 0.6643980
#7  0.6643980 0.7585417
#8  0.7585417 0.8660254
#9  0.8660254 0.9887393
#10 0.9887393 1.1288415
#11 1.1288415 1.2887959
#12 1.2887959 1.4714155
#13 1.4714155 1.6799118
#14 1.6799118 1.9179517
#15 1.9179517 2.1897213
#16 2.1897213 2.5000000
```

or for range 0.3 to 10:

```
tt <- exp(seq(log(0.3), log(10), length.out=17))
data.frame(Lower=tt[-length(tt)], Upper=tt[-1])
#       Lower      Upper
#1  0.3000000  0.3735091
#2  0.3735091  0.4650301
#3  0.4650301  0.5789766
#4  0.5789766  0.7208434
#5  0.7208434  0.8974719
#6  0.8974719  1.1173797
#7  1.1173797  1.3911716
#8  1.3911716  1.7320508
#9  1.7320508  2.1564557
#10 2.1564557  2.6848527
#11 2.6848527  3.3427230
#12 3.3427230  4.1617915
#13 4.1617915  5.1815565
#14 5.1815565  6.4511948
#15 6.4511948  8.0319330
#16 8.0319330 10.0000000
```